# Guardar contraseña encriptada en BD [#C WF, SQL]

Tags: c#, sql, windows

Alguno me podria indicar como guardar una contraseña encriptada en una base de datos, esa contraseña es de un usuario.

```
oUsuario.Contraseña= .......................................
```

ADO.NET entity framework, sql esta conectado a mi proyecto!

saludos

Comment: 3 cosas: Primero ve a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que puedas ver cómo es que funciona el sitio. Luego ve a cómo preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Finalmente, ¿qué has realizado? Edita tu pregunta agregando todo intento desarrrollado, caso contrario tu pregunta queda como demasiado amplia y/o basada en opiniones, pues hay varios caminos para desarrollar la solución y considerando que la pregunta carece de intentos, potencialmente podría ser cerrada. Intenta, tú puedes, edita y agrega los errores que tengas, la comunidad te dará una mano :D

Answer (score 0):

La constraseña no se guarda encriptada, se guarda como `hash`.

La idea es que tengas que comparar el valor que se ingresa al autenticar con el valor que tienes en ela db, si conciden entonces pasa el login.

Aqui lo explico

[Login – Usando Password con Hash](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/05/login-usando-password-con-hash.html)

Puede aplicar un encode el password

```
public static string EncodePassword(string originalPassword)
{
    SHA1 sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] inputBytes = (new UnicodeEncoding()).GetBytes(originalPassword);
    byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

Para autenticar aplicando el mismo encode que usaste al insertar el registro

```
public static bool Autenticar(string usuario, string password)
{
    string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*)
                      FROM Usuarios
                      WHERE NombreLogin = @nombre AND Password = @password";


    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", usuario);

        string hash = Helper.EncodePassword(string.Concat(usuario, password));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", hash);

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

        return count > 0;
    }
}
```